# How to edit laravel passport token's expires_at field

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I am trying to edit `expires_at` field of my `token` with a `middleware` like bellow

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Closure;
use Auth;

class Refresh
{

    /**
     * @param $request
     * @param Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $token = Auth::user()->token();
        $expiresDate = $token->expires_at;
        $currentDate = Carbon::now();
        $diff = date_diff_in_minutes($currentDate, $expiresDate);
        $baseExpire = site_config('token_expires_minutes');
        if ($diff > 0 && $diff < $baseExpire) {
            $token->update([
                'expires_at' => (new Carbon($expiresDate))->addMinutes(intval($baseExpire - $diff))
            ]);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Updating token's `expires_at` field in each api requests works fine.

But the token expires at the first `expires_at` date.

I know there is a `refresh_token` method that i can use for this but i have some issues with refresh tokens and because of that i have to increase token's life time without revoking.

Do you know why this happening? How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#configuration), the default token lifetime should be set in your `AuthServiceProvider.php` by calling the `Passport::tokensExpireIn()` function in your `boot()` method.

Example:

```
public function boot() {
    ...

    $baseExpire = site_config('token_expires_minutes');

    Passport::tokensExpireIn(now()->addMinutes($baseExpire));
}
```

**EDIT**

Sorry, I misunderstood your original question. Unfortunately, it's not possible to change the expiration of a generated token, since the expiration is encoded into the actual token string (Laravel uses https://github.com/lcobucci/jwt to generate and validate tokens). However, you may look into overriding the passport validation to check the expiration on the table rather than using the default package.

Comment: Yes i know that. i want to change it after token created