# Expired token Laravel Passport get authorized

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I'm using `Laravel 5.6` to build a `API` and `Laravel Passport` to manage the authentication of my users. The front end relies on a `vue.js` application.

All the users are going to be granted a `Personnal Access Token` which is linked to `Laravel Personal Access Client`

In the table `oauth_access_tokens` I set the `expires_at` a year ago

### Routes api.php

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1', 'middleware' => ['auth:api','permission:access admin']], function() {
 Route::get('/test', 'API\TestController@getAll');
}
```

#### Situation

Yet, when I call `api/v1/test` the middleware `auth:api` does not trigger any error. In other words, even if my token is expired (but not revoked) it goes through.

When setting `revoked` to `1` I get an error which told me I'm not authorized (normal since my token is revoked)

#### Questions

Is that normal ? Am I misunderstanding a point ?

Comment: Well, the prefix means specifically what it says... did you try /v1/test to see if the error happens?

Comment: It is not a naming issue. I updated the post hoping it is a bit clearer

Comment: I think you mistook the order though, should be api/v1/test

Comment: My bad I changed it. Thanks for the notice

Comment: Leo, apparently this option of expiration does not work specifically for Personal Access Tokens, it says here: https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/162

But there is also a way around it, described in the same link shortly after this explanation. The solution from @dgutman10 seems quite efficient.

Comment: @LéoCoco See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51801351/how-to-edit-laravel-passport-tokens-expires-at-field/51801730#51801730 on a similar issue. Apparently, the package that Laravel uses for generating the tokens encodes the expiration into the token string. You would have to override functionality or manually check the database before validating the token.

Comment: @LéoCoco did you resolve it?